# USPS Postnet barcodes

Tags: barcodes

After searching on-and-off for several weeks I haven't found an answer to this. Is there a LaTeX package to generate USPS zip+4 barcodes on an envelope?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [envlab](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/envlab/) package does envelopes, labels, and barcodes.

Comment: Thanks! Envlab does exactly what I want, however, when printing on a #10 envelope, it's scaled down about two-thirds the correct size. If I print it on letter paper it looks normal. I had to put in a custom page size statement from my previous business envelope template for it to print the correct size.

Comment: Don't suppose I can print my own postage stamps? :-)

Comment: Glad you liked it!

Comment: @Kent Sure, but please don't quote me when <random 3-letter agency> politely inquires where you got the idea..

Answer (score 1):

There are several packages that might be useful.

- [barcodes](http://ctan.org/pkg/barcodes)
- [makebarcode](http://ctan.org/pkg/makebarcode)
- [pst-barcode](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-barcode)

Since I never used them, I'm not sure if they do what you want.