# LaTeX 2D-PDF (PDF417)

Tags: barcodes

Maybe easy question but i tried searching for answer without any luck. (could be on wrong sites).

If anyone knows how can i make 2DPDF ([PDF417](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CD4QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417&ei=h7gcUbKXA4SMtQa1vIHQBw&usg=AFQjCNHOAmYlZatoddi1cSBXy0P3AHvYdQ&bvm=bv.42452523,d.Yms)) bar codes in LaTeX ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 8):

[`pst-barcode`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-barcode) can do this. Since it requires PSTricks, you need to compile this using `xelatex` or `latex`. If you want to use `pdflatex`, you can add `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` to the preamble:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(2in,0.3in)
\psbarcode{0123456789}{}{pdf417}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, have to check and see possibility of installing additional packages.

Comment: @Jake I guess your solution doesn't work on Windows. I get this error:

Package ifplatform Warning: 
    shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.
)
\c@app@runs=\count111

! Package auto-pst-pdf Error: 
    "shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:
    auto-pst-pdf will not work!

Comment: The MWE shown doesn't produce any output and gives the error: Package pst-pdf Warning: File `barcode-pics.pdf' not found. and then there are few indications to manually generate the document using dvips

Answer (score 1):

I googled your question and I found two useful posts about [barcode](http://www.barcodelib.com/net_barcode/barcode_symbologies/pdf417.html) generation in LaTex, hope it can be of some help

1. [Is there a good LaTeX package for generating barcodes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6895/is-there-a-good-latex-package-for-generating-barcodes)
2. [Barcodes in LaTeX](http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=993)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)